# React Form + React Redux; unable to create form

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Case**: Trying to create a signup form which receives the user input values from a simple form **and** one extra field which dependes on the url.

```
  FORM     +      URL              
| name  |      
| mail  |     /signup/empire    => signUpInGroup(user, group)
| xxx   |            --------   
| terms |             group
```

**Approach**

**[1. Action]** `sign-up.js`

```
export default function signUp(userFormValues) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    // everything works fine with userFormValues, later I'll try to add group
  }
}
```

**[2. Form]** The form is named as `sign-up-form.js`

```
function SignUp({handleSubmit}) {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Field ...>
    ...
    </form>
  )
}

const SignUpForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'signUp'
})
export default SignUpForm
```

**[3. Component]**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import signUpInCompany from '....actions/sign-up'
import SignUpForm from '......components/sign-up-form'

function SignUp({signUp, group}) {
  console.log(group) // FINE!!!!!!
  return (
    <div>
      <SignUpForm handleSubmit={signUp} />
    </div>
  )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  signUp
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(cssModules(SignUp, styles))
```

=======================

This works fine until I try to send `group` to the action function. All I want is to be able to play with `userFormValues` **and** `group` in my action function.

**Failed try #1**

**[Bind group to the function]**

```
function SignUp({signUp, group}) {
  console.log(group) // FINE!!!!!!
  return (
    <div>
      <SignUpForm handleSubmit={signUp.bind({ group })} />
    </div>
  )
}    

export default function signUp(userFormValues) {
  // expected this to be { group: 'empire' } but got undefined
  return (dispatch) => {
 }
}
```

**Failed try #2**

**[Create an scope]**

```
function SignUp({signUp, group}) {
  console.log(group) // FINE!!!!!!
  return (
    <div>
      <SignUpForm handleSubmit={signUp(group)} />
    </div>
  )
}   

export default function signUp(group) {
  return (userFormValues) => {
     // nothing works 
     return (dispatch) => {
        // blah blah
     }
   }
}
```

**Failed try #3**

**[Immediate call function]**

```
function SignUp({signUp, group}) {
  console.log(group) // FINE!!!!!!
  return (
    <div>
      <SignUpForm handleSubmit={(val) => signUp(group)(val) } />
    </div>
  )
}   

export default function signUp(group) {
  return (userFormValues) => {
    // nothing works 
      return (dispatch) => {
        // blah blah
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: try variations with <SignUpForm handleSubmit={signUp.bind(this) /> :)
First argument of bind is context, it should be this in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, KISS principle wins. Just use **`Object.assign()`**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import signUpInCompany from '....actions/sign-up'
import SignUpForm from '......components/sign-up-form'

function SignUp({signUp, group}) {
  console.log(group) // FINE!!!!!!
  return (
    <div>
      <SignUpForm handleSubmit={(body) => signUp(Object.assign(body, {group}))} />
    </div>
  )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  signUp
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(cssModules(SignUp, styles))
```